# Linux exit command does nothing

Tags: linux, bash

I'm new to Linux and am trying to create a simple program that checks if a user exists, if exists - exits the terminal, if not - creates it. I think I've done everything except exiting the terminal.

This is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_name=newUser

if [ $(getent passwd $user_name) ]
then
    echo "User $user_name already exists!"
    exit
else
    echo "The user $user_name doesn't exist and will be added"
    sudo useradd -d /home/mint/newUser $user_name
fi
```

edit: As I said i'm new to Linux. Can someone edit my code and post it, I need to add it to a script, maybe i can close it with while function?

Comment: Commands or scripts that exit the terminal is usually not a good idea, unless it's behavior is ***well*** documented and all users really know about it. If I ran a command and the terminal windows just closed for me (especially after it wrote something that I didn't have time to see) would make me angry enough to never use that command again.

Comment: I'm looking at some problems and the one i'm solving right now want's me to exit the program if the user is existing. Maybe I can echo that the problem is going to close and close it after. It is a part of a script.

Comment: Exiting *the program* is fine, and is already what your code does.

Answer (score 2):

The `exit` command simply exits the current script. If you want to exit the terminal, you need to `exit` (or otherwise terminate) the program which is running in that terminal.

A common way to accomplish this is to make the process which wants to `exit` run as a function in your interactive shell.

```
add_user () { /path/to/your/script "$@" || exit; }
```

In this case, though, I would simply advise you to keep your script as is, and leave it to the user to decide whether or not they want to close their terminal.

By the way, the construct

```
if [ $(command) ]
```

will be true if the output from `command` is a non-empty string. The correct way to check the exit code from `command` is simply

```
if command
```

possibly with output redirection if you don't want the invoking user to see any output from `command`.

The function above also requires your scripit to exit with an explicit error; probably change it to `exit 1` to explicitly communicate an error condition back to the caller.

```
#!/bin/bash
# First parameter is name of user to add
user_name=$1

# Quote variable; examine exit code
if getent passwd "$user_name" >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    # Notice addition of script name and redirect to stderr
    echo "$0: User $user_name already exists!" >&2
     # Explicitly exit with nonzero exit code
    exit 1
else
    # script name & redirect as above
    echo "$0: The user $user_name doesn't exist and will be added" >&2
    # Quote argument
    sudo useradd -d /home/mint/newUser "$user_name"
fi
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, does this answer the original question?

Comment: @Sami The question isn't very clear, but the OP posted a comment (now deleted as unnecessary verbosity, I guess) which seemed to indicate satisfaction with this answer.

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611648/exit-terminal-after-running-a-bash-script). I will summarise here:

In your script, as you may have noticed, `exit` will only exit the current script.

A user-friendly way to achieve what you're after is to use the `exit` command to set a suitable return code and call your script like `./<script> && exit`.

If you really want the hard way, use

```
kill -9 $PPID
```

which will attempt to kill the enclosing process.

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` unless you know that other signals don't work. Needlessly using `-9` prevents the victim from doing its cleanup actions - it could create bigger problems than the one you were trying to solve in the first place.

Comment: Yes, this was addressed in the original post on askubuntu.com too.